# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization, security-context

1. I have an application exporting web services, with a configured Spring Security `SecurityFilterChain` (with `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` among others, which is required for the rest).
2. My application also uses Spring Security to secure method invocations.

I have following error when method security is triggered:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

The 2nd part requires an `Authentication` in `SecurityContextHolder` as showed in `org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor` (line 195):

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

But, `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` removes it before method invocation is triggered, as shown in 
`org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` (line 84)

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

What can I do to have this object in `SecurityContextHolder` when method invocation is triggered?

Thank you in advance.

I'm using Spring Security 3.0.8-RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my application is placed over [Apache CXF DOSGi 1.4](http://cxf.apache.org/dosgi-releases.html) to generate REST endpoints. Apache CXF interceptors cause an unexpected behaviour and `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` is called before finishing the request processing.

More information about this bug can be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DOSGI-183).

Answer (score 3):

`SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` will be called only after request processing completion. So normally all your application logic code will be executed **before** this line, and there is no problem at all. But the problem may be present if you execute some new thread in your code (by default security context will be not propogated). If this is your case then you can [try to force context propogation to child thread](http://ogrigas.eu/spring/2010/04/inherit-spring-security-context-in-child-threads). If you use only one thread then make sure that all your code is covered by spring security filter chain (may be you have some custom filter that executed **around** spring security filter chain?).